# Socket.io reconnection firing no matter what i do

Tags: javascript, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Using socket.io 1.4.5.

It seems no matter what I do, I cannot prevent socket.io from firing the reconnection event or destroying the client socket when there are interruptions with the internet connection.

On the client side, I have: 
 reconnectionDelay: 99999999,
timeout: 99999999999,
            reconnection: false,

And yet, if the internet disconnects, the socket will become undefined (after 20 seconds or so) and the reconnection event fires when the internet goes back on.

My ultimate goal is to use the same exact socket on the server and on the client (regardless of how long it's been since they've communicated) unless that socket is explicitly disconnected on the server. I cannot have the socket reconnecting at will, because I store data on the socket and use the socket.id extensively in my application. IF the socket and socket id were to suddenly change, the application breaks.

Comment: It sounds like you want a client session that is based on a cookie when the socket connects rather than trying to create a permanent socket object.  Then, you store the info in that session which you can hook up to anytime a new socket connection comes in from that client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You've to pass some unique variable on handshake and keep data by that variable. 
Regeneration of `socket.id` is normal behavior of socket.io.

In my practice I'm doing initial request to server to create `slot` variable and keep it `slots` collection in `mongodb` and after I'm creating connection by defining that `slot` variable as handshake.

or let's just simplify answer to Your question and use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

also a little "hack" use namespaces logic: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#custom-namespaces

BONUS:

here is quick solution:

clientside:

```
function genUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d/16);
        return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};

var namespace = localStorage.getItem("namespace");
if(!namespace) {
  namespace = genUUID();
  localStorage.setItem("namespace", namespace);
}

var connect = function (ns) {
    return io.connect(ns, {
       query: 'ns='+ns   // this is handshake variable `ns`
    });
}

var socket = connect('/'+namespace);
```

backend:

```
const 
  url = require('url'),
  sharedData = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const handshake = url.parse(socket.handshake.url, true);
  const ns = handshake.query ? handshake.query.ns : 'default';
  console.log('GOT CONNECTION TO NS: '+ns);

  io.of(ns).on('connection', (socket) => {
    if(!sharedData[ns]) sharedData[ns] = {};
    // put socket code here
    socket.on('some-event', (data) => {
      sharedData[ns]['some-event'] = data.someData;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, my entire application both client and server is build around using socket.id as a unique identifier. Rewriting that would be a painful experience. surely there must be some way to retain the original socket on both client and server even after a reconnect.

Comment: There are 2 choises: 1. rewrite Your code, 2. rewrite the code of socket.io-client. Pick one of them (:

Comment: can you explain the thing that you linked to? There is no description on the product page, just installation instruction. i assume this is some kind of session handler for socket? How would this help retain my sockets?

Comment: The link that I gave You has an example in bottom with handshake. It simplifies the process of creating and handling that `slot` variable that I use manually by keeping session context.

Comment: I'm not looking for examples. I'm looking for a brief overview or description of what this project does and is for.

Comment: simply: it creates `socket.handshake.session` object that can keep data and reread it on reconnect.

Comment: hmm, thanks, could be useful but looks like i will have to do a lot of rewriting no matter what.

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer, check it. Idea is to create dynamically hashed namespace and just track it inside of namespace. that's only stable manual thing that You can take under Your control

Comment: is there any way to simply not have a connection timeout, so if the internet goes off, then goes back on, it will be re-using the old socket no matter what? I don't care if this causes performance problems, i can figure out how to manually disconnect sockets that have actually permanently disconnected. turning off connection timeouts completely would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @ChrisScott I've added BONUS part to my answer, that show's example of using namespaces as socket.id grouping.